# How to read (decode) .tfrecords file, see the images inside and do augmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, decode, tfrecord, data-augmentation

I have a `.tfrecords` file and I want to extract, see the images in the file and augment them.
I am using https://colab.research.google.com
TensorFlow version: 2.3.0

And for the following code

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("*path.tfrecords")

for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(1):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
    print(example)
```

I am facing the following output:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "depth"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 3
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "height"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 333
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image_raw"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value:
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "label"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 16
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "width"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 500
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: from .tfrecords you want to see image?

Comment: Exactly, I want to print one or two images from the file! @AkashDesai

Comment: @lko-SOF Is your .tfrecord file secret? Can you share somehow small part of it, or whole? So that we can try to write a script that extracts images from it.

Comment: Hello @Arty, Please find the data set uploaded in the following link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TnXFf-fodf9Z33g4pheSD4-Wq1Z87pzd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code that can extract your .tfrecord images as .png format.

To run next codes you need to install one time pip modules through `pip install tensorflow tensorflow_addons pillow numpy matplotlib`.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf, PIL.Image, numpy as np

raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('max_32_set.tfrecords')

for i, raw_record in enumerate(raw_dataset.take(3)):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
    info = {}
    for k, v in example.features.feature.items():
        if k == 'image_raw':
            info[k] = v.bytes_list.value[0]
        elif k in ['depth', 'height', 'width']:
            info[k] = v.int64_list.value[0]
    img_arr = np.frombuffer(info['image_raw'], dtype = np.uint8).reshape(
        info['height'], info['width'], info['depth']
    )
    # You can use img_arr numpy array above to directly augment/preprocess
    # your image without saving it to .png.
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(img_arr)
    img.save(f'max_32_set.tfrecords.{str(i).zfill(5)}.png')
```

First image from dataset:

[image: img]

Below is code for drawing number of images per each label. Labels inside `max_32_set.tfrecords` file are represented as integers (not string names), probably names of labels are located in separate small file with meta information about dataset.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('max_32_set.tfrecords')

labels_cnts = {}
for i, raw_record in enumerate(raw_dataset.as_numpy_iterator()):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record)
    info = {}
    for k, v in example.features.feature.items():
        if k == 'label':
            info[k] = v.int64_list.value[0]
    labels_cnts[info['label']] = labels_cnts.get(info['label'], 0) + 1

x, y = zip(*sorted(labels_cnts.items(), key = lambda e: e[0]))
plt.xlabel('label')
plt.ylabel('num images')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.show()
```

Plot for `max_32_set.tfrecords`:

[image: plot]

Next code does augmentation using gaussian noise and gaussian blur, augmented tfrecord dataset is saved to `max_32_set.augmented.tfrecords` file:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf, tensorflow_addons as tfa, PIL.Image, numpy as np, math

c_inp_fname = 'max_32_set.tfrecords'
c_out_fname = 'max_32_set.augmented.tfrecords'
c_augment_types = ('noise', 'blur', 'noise_blur', 'noise_blur_mirror')
c_res_class_size = None # If None then auto configured to maximal class size

def calc_labels():
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(c_inp_fname)
    cnts, labels = {}, []
    for i, raw_record in enumerate(raw_dataset):
        example = tf.train.Example()
        example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
        label = example.features.feature['label'].int64_list.value[0]
        cnts[label] = cnts.get(label, 0) + 1
        labels.append(label)
    return cnts, labels

def img_gen():
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(c_inp_fname)
    for i, raw_record in enumerate(raw_dataset):
        example = tf.train.Example()
        example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
        info = {}
        for k, v in example.features.feature.items():
            if k == 'image_raw':
                info[k] = v.bytes_list.value[0]
            elif k in ['depth', 'height', 'width']:
                info[k] = v.int64_list.value[0]
        img_arr = np.frombuffer(info['image_raw'], dtype = np.uint8).reshape(
            info['height'], info['width'], info['depth']
        )
        yield example, img_arr
        
def gaussian_noise(inp, stddev):
    noise = tf.random.normal(shape = tf.shape(inp), mean = 0.0, stddev = stddev, dtype = inp.dtype)
    return inp + noise
        
def augment(a, cnt):
    min_noise_stddev, max_noise_stddev = 5., 20.
    blur_kern, min_blur_stddev, max_blur_stddev = 3, 1., 5.
    
    assert cnt >= 1
    pad_a = lambda x: np.pad(x, (
        (0, 2 ** math.ceil(math.log(x.shape[0]) / math.log(2)) - x.shape[0]),
        (0, 2 ** math.ceil(math.log(x.shape[1]) / math.log(2)) - x.shape[1]),
        (0, 0)), constant_values = 0)
    post_a = lambda x: np.clip(x[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]], 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
    yield 'orig', a
    cnt -= 1
    res = []
    fcnt = math.ceil(cnt / len(c_augment_types))
    linsp = lambda l, r, c: [(l + (i + 1) * (r - l) / (c + 1)) for i in range(c)]
    for noise_stddev, blur_stddev in zip(linsp(min_noise_stddev, max_noise_stddev, fcnt), linsp(min_blur_stddev, max_blur_stddev, fcnt)):
        if 'noise' in c_augment_types:
            #yield 'noise', post_a(tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev = noise_stddev)(prep_a, training = True).numpy())
            res.append(('noise', post_a(gaussian_noise(a.astype(np.float32), stddev = noise_stddev).numpy())))
        if 'blur' in c_augment_types:
            res.append(('blur', post_a(tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d(pad_a(a).astype(np.float32), filter_shape = blur_kern, sigma = blur_stddev).numpy())))
        if 'noise_blur' in c_augment_types or 'noise_blur_mirror' in c_augment_types:
            nbr = post_a(tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d(
                pad_a(gaussian_noise(a.astype(np.float32), stddev = noise_stddev).numpy()),
                filter_shape = blur_kern, sigma = blur_stddev).numpy())
            if 'noise_blur' in c_augment_types:
                res.append(('noise_blur', nbr))
            if 'noise_blur_mirror' in c_augment_types:
                res.append(('noise_blur_mirror', tf.image.flip_left_right(nbr).numpy().astype(np.uint8)))
    assert cnt <= len(res) <= cnt + len(c_augment_types), (cnt, len(res), len(c_augment_types))
    yield from res[:cnt]

def process():
    labels_cnts, labels = calc_labels()
    max_class_size = max(labels_cnts.values())
    if c_res_class_size is not None:
        assert max_class_size <= c_res_class_size, f'Maximal class size is {max_class_size}, while requested res class size is smaller, {c_res_class_size}!'
        class_size = c_res_class_size
    else:
        class_size = max_class_size
    cur_labels_cnts = {}
    for iimg, (proto, imga) in enumerate(img_gen()):
        label = proto.features.feature['label'].int64_list.value[0]
        cur_labels_cnts[label] = cur_labels_cnts.get(label, 0) + 1
        need_cnt = class_size // labels_cnts[label] + int(cur_labels_cnts[label] <= class_size % labels_cnts[label])
        for iaug, (taug, aug) in enumerate(augment(imga, need_cnt)):
            #PIL.Image.fromarray(aug).save(f'max_32_set.tfrecords.aug.{str(iimg).zfill(5)}.{iaug}_{taug}.png')
            protoc = type(proto)()
            protoc.ParseFromString(proto.SerializeToString())
            protoc.features.feature['image_raw'].bytes_list.value[0] = aug.tobytes()
            yield protoc.SerializeToString()
        if (iimg % 10) == 0:
            print(iimg, ' ', sep = '', end = '', flush = True)
            
def main():
    assert tf.executing_eagerly()
    tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter(c_out_fname).write(
        tf.data.TFRecordDataset.from_generator(process, tf.string)
    )

main()
```

Example augmented images:

Original:

[image]

Noised:

[image]

Blurred:

[image]

Noised-blurred:

[image]

Noised-blurred-mirrored:

[image]

Number of images per label after augmentation (exactly balanced 30 images per label):

[image]

---

Same augmentation as above but for the case of input and output folders with labeled images, instead of TFRecordDataset, change `c_inp_dir` and `c_out_dir` to your folders paths:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf, tensorflow_addons as tfa, PIL.Image, numpy as np, math, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c_inp_dir = './images/'
c_out_dir = './images_out/'
c_augment_types = ('noise', 'blur', 'noise_blur', 'noise_blur_mirror')
c_res_class_size = None # If None then auto configured to maximal class size

def calc_labels(dirn = None):
    if dirn is None:
        dirn = c_inp_dir
    cnts, labels = {}, []
    for label in sorted(os.listdir(f'{dirn}')):
        label = int(label)
        labels.append(label)
        cnts[label] = len(os.listdir(f'{dirn}/{label}/'))
    return cnts, labels

def img_gen():
    cnts = {}
    for label in sorted(os.listdir(c_inp_dir)):
        label = int(label)
        for fname in sorted(os.listdir(f'{c_inp_dir}/{label}/')):
            img_arr = np.array(PIL.Image.open(f'{c_inp_dir}/{label}/{fname}'))
            yield label, img_arr, fname
        
def gaussian_noise(inp, stddev):
    noise = tf.random.normal(shape = tf.shape(inp), mean = 0.0, stddev = stddev, dtype = inp.dtype)
    return inp + noise
        
def augment(a, cnt):
    min_noise_stddev, max_noise_stddev = 5., 20.
    blur_kern, min_blur_stddev, max_blur_stddev = 3, 1., 5.
    
    assert cnt >= 1
    pad_a = lambda x: np.pad(x, (
        (0, 2 ** math.ceil(math.log(x.shape[0]) / math.log(2)) - x.shape[0]),
        (0, 2 ** math.ceil(math.log(x.shape[1]) / math.log(2)) - x.shape[1]),
        (0, 0)), constant_values = 0)
    post_a = lambda x: np.clip(x[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]], 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
    yield 'orig', a
    cnt -= 1
    res = []
    fcnt = math.ceil(cnt / len(c_augment_types))
    linsp = lambda l, r, c: [(l + (i + 1) * (r - l) / (c + 1)) for i in range(c)]
    for noise_stddev, blur_stddev in zip(linsp(min_noise_stddev, max_noise_stddev, fcnt), linsp(min_blur_stddev, max_blur_stddev, fcnt)):
        if 'noise' in c_augment_types:
            #yield 'noise', post_a(tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev = noise_stddev)(prep_a, training = True).numpy())
            res.append(('noise', post_a(gaussian_noise(a.astype(np.float32), stddev = noise_stddev).numpy())))
        if 'blur' in c_augment_types:
            res.append(('blur', post_a(tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d(pad_a(a).astype(np.float32), filter_shape = blur_kern, sigma = blur_stddev).numpy())))
        if 'noise_blur' in c_augment_types or 'noise_blur_mirror' in c_augment_types:
            nbr = post_a(tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d(
                pad_a(gaussian_noise(a.astype(np.float32), stddev = noise_stddev).numpy()),
                filter_shape = blur_kern, sigma = blur_stddev).numpy())
            if 'noise_blur' in c_augment_types:
                res.append(('noise_blur', nbr))
            if 'noise_blur_mirror' in c_augment_types:
                res.append(('noise_blur_mirror', tf.image.flip_left_right(nbr).numpy().astype(np.uint8)))
    assert cnt <= len(res) <= cnt + len(c_augment_types), (cnt, len(res), len(c_augment_types))
    yield from res[:cnt]

def process():
    labels_cnts, labels = calc_labels()
    max_class_size = max(labels_cnts.values())
    if c_res_class_size is not None:
        assert max_class_size <= c_res_class_size, f'Maximal class size is {max_class_size}, while requested res class size is smaller, {c_res_class_size}!'
        class_size = c_res_class_size
    else:
        class_size = max_class_size
    
    cur_labels_cnts = {}
    for iimg, (label, imga, fname) in enumerate(img_gen()):
        os.makedirs(f'{c_out_dir}/{label}/', exist_ok = True)
        cur_labels_cnts[label] = cur_labels_cnts.get(label, 0) + 1
        need_cnt = class_size // labels_cnts[label] + int(cur_labels_cnts[label] <= class_size % labels_cnts[label])
        for iaug, (taug, aug) in enumerate(augment(imga, need_cnt)):
            PIL.Image.fromarray(aug).save(f'{c_out_dir}/{label}/{fname}.{iaug}_{taug}.png')
        if (iimg % 10) == 0:
            print(iimg, ' ', sep = '', end = '', flush = True)
            
def plot_cnts(dirn):
    labels_cnts = calc_labels(dirn)[0]
    x, y = zip(*sorted(labels_cnts.items(), key = lambda e: e[0]))
    plt.xlabel('label')
    plt.ylabel('num images')
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xticks(x)
    plt.show()
            
def main():
    process()
    plot_cnts(c_inp_dir)
    plot_cnts(c_out_dir)

main()
```

Comment: Hello @Arty , would it be possible from you to show how to do the same but in case images are in 5 folders. Each i folder has the i class images. To be taken into consideration, in this case the images are .jpg

Comment: @Iko-SOF As you can see currently I use `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` as input and output. For your current case what do you want? As I understand you don't have TFRecordDataset anymore, but just folder with images. What about output, do you want it to be in which format? Also folder with images, or output should be as TFRecordDataset?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Arty , the output will be in again in .jpg format (so no more tfrecord dataset), I thought it's better to make it in a separate question, and no need to disturb your here answer. Could you please have the new question in the link below?

Comment: @Iko-SOF I think I'll extend my current answer here with adoption for your folder case, because most of the code will be same, I don't think it is good for StackOverflow to copy almost whole code from one answer to another with doing small modifications. StackOverflow tend to make one rich answer and mark other questions as duplicate.

Comment: @Iko-SOF Just updated my answer above. Added to the very end of it piece of code adopted for your case of folders with images. You can see in the beginning of code `c_inp_dir` and `c_out_dir` variables containing paths to your input/output folders. That code does augmentation in the beginning and then draws two plots, first with unmodified images counts, after when you close window, it draws second plot with augmented images counts.

Comment: Thanks for your modification. I am still applying your code and the data set I have is quite large so that would take a bit more time. I will approve it in the other question once I had the results up. @Arty

Comment: I have a question please. Do you have experience in CNN? or can you help in building CNN model to be tested on both cases (before and after balancing the folders of .jpg photos) @Arty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227841/discussion-between-arty-and-iko-sof).

Comment: @Iko-SOF Our discussion is continued [in this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227841/), please go there.

Comment: Hello @Arty , could you please comment the scripts you wrote above. The comments would help to let the code more understood

Comment: @Iko-SOF I have several scripts in my answer. Which one is not understood by you? The very last one?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code right before the last one ..... "Next code does augmentation using gaussian noise and gaussian blur, augmented tfrecord dataset is saved to max_32_set.augmented.tfrecords file:"

Comment: @Iko-SOF I'll try to explain this code here, because it is to large to comment all lines. Just ask questions what you don't understand there. 1) This code loads tfrecord images 2) computes number of images per label 3) applies several types of filters `('noise', 'blur', 'noise_blur', 'noise_blur_mirror')`, noise adds random noise, blur blurs image, noise_blur adds noise plus blurs, noise_blur_mirror adds noise blurs and mirrors image (flips left and right). 4) resulting images are saved back to tfrecord. 5) number of images per label are drawn later using matplotlib graph.

Comment: Do we apply all the augment_types to each image or does each image getting randomly a type of the augmentation? Also, could you please give a short overview about (def process) function

Comment: @Iko-SOF `process()` function computes how many extra images are needed for each label. Then it calls `augment()` passing current image of label and final count needed to achieve. Then `augment()` applies filters to image, augment knows how many final images are needed, so it basically applies filters from left to right taking types from `c_augment_types`, it applies these filters until we reach needed count. Also if we applied already all filters and not reached final count then it starts from first filter again with different random params.

Comment: Thanks for your description